# Firebase Storage multiple image array GetDownloadURL how we can fix it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

We want to get the link of the images we added as an array with the GetDownloadUrl method.

I cannot add the link returned from GetDownloadUrl to the firestore as an array.

Here is the code:

```
  const [multipleImage, setImage] = useState([]);
  const [multipleImageFake, setImageFake] = useState([]);

    const task = storegeRef.putFile(uploadUri[i].imgURL).then((url)=>{
           
          });
          setImageFake([{"name":"rest"},{"name":"rest"}]);
```

and this is the firestore query

```
 .collection('patients')
      .doc(id)
      .collection('transactions')
      .doc(date)
      .set({
        userId: auth().currentUser.uid,
        postImg: multipleImageFake,
        catchDate: date,
        processDate: firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        diagnosticText: text,
      })
```

NOTE: when I use putFile method, it gives me MetaData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Determining the download URL requires a call to the server, so it is an asynchronous operation. Any code that needs the download URL, need to be inside the `then()` callback:

We want to get the link of the images we added as an array with the GetDownloadUrl method.

I cannot add the link returned from GetDownloadUrl to the firestore as an array.

Here is the code:

```
const [multipleImage, setImage] = useState([]);
const [multipleImageFake, setImageFake] = useState([]);

const task = storegeRef.putFile(uploadUri[i].imgURL).then((url)=>{
  // Here you can access the URL value and for example write it to Firestore           
});

// Here you can't
```